# Firestore not working with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, aws-lambda, google-cloud-firestore

I have initialized **firebase** inside my **AWS lambda** function using the **Node.js 8.10** runtime. This is the relevant code:

```
'use strict';

const https = require('https'),
      firebase = require('firebase-admin'),
      admin = require('firebase-admin');
//Initialize firebase
let serviceAccount = require('./one-deed-6b407-firebase-adminsdk-ha9ud-3c7ddb5906.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)

});
let db = admin.firestore();
```

Later in the code I created a **firestore** database:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
   var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

   var setAda = docRef.set({
     first: 'Ada',
     last: 'Lovelace',
     born: 1815
   });
}
```

However, the document in question was not added even though the code works properly when I run I locally.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  What does this mean? - "the database in question was not added"

Comment: @DougStevenson the database was not added to the users collection.

Comment: I meant document, sorry.

Comment: Do you need to do something with the promise returned by set()?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: @DougStevenson none of the firestore functions work.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the execution time of the function. It should be quite small. 
The lambda code is not waiting for the Firestore function to be executed.

As @doug-stevenson pointed out you are not using the promise.
Change the lambda function to async and put a await in front of the set.
I hope that helps.

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
var docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

let setAda = await docRef.set({
 first: 'Ada',
 last: 'Lovelace',
 born: 1815
});
}
```